# Maven eclipse formatter doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, formatting

We want to use maven formatter which uses eclipse's `formatter.xml` file to format java code of our project. We have tried [Maven java formatter plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-java-formatter-plugin/), [Maven eclipse format](http://mvneclipsefmt.sourceforge.net) and maven eclipse plugin. All the plugins are formatting code differently and that formatting is very much different from formatted file produced by eclipse formatting.

Maven java formatter plugin is closest to eclipse formatting but it is unable to split line to specified length when that line contains generic parameters. Also javadoc formatting is not same in it as compared to eclipse.

If any one has used eclipse formatter with maven and if that works similar to eclipse internal formatter please let me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with maven-java-formatter-plugin. I have published a fork that resolves it for Eclipse 3.7.1 SR1 at https://github.com/benalexau/maven-java-formatter-plugin/ which you are welcome to use. Note I have logged http://code.google.com/p/maven-java-formatter-plugin/issues/detail?id=18&thanks=18&ts=1324185588 against the original project to merge these changes with a little luck. HTH.

Comment: The referenced fork no longer exists at that address, does not exist in Maven Central, and even if it did, Eclipse 3.7.1 still has issues with extra trailing whitespace in empty javadoc lines.

Comment: My fork now lives at https://github.com/acegi/xml-format-maven-plugin and is available from Maven Central. The original Google Code project has long since disappeared.

Comment: The original code moved to GitHub, and now lives at https://github.com/revelc/formatter-maven-plugin where a very small group of people are keeping it alive. Feel free to join us there to help with new features, bug fixing, and releasing to Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a workaround using the below commands.

- **To format:** `net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.10.0:format`.
- **To validate:** `net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.10.0:validate`.

In eclipse, you can configure the maven goal as shown below.

[image]